# How to create Multiple splash screens depend on conditions xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I wondered if it is possible to create Multiple splash screens (Android , IOS) which displayed according to user state for example

```
switch (splash)
{
case one 
// show splash one 
case two
//show splash two
}
```

is it possible ? or any sample for this ?

I think if i can change Main interface in ios from code it will works fine
the same case in android , any help ?

Comment: It is up to you what to show to the user, just disable or make "transparent" the default splash screen and use `Page`s to represent your custom splash screens.

Comment: Didn't manage to do it. A workaround: showing a quick first common splash then with a popup and a loading indicator showing second different splash obtained from internet at realtime depending on tenant.

Comment: @EvZ any sample for that ?

Comment: @NickKovalsky but i want to show only one different in day time or randomly catch splash screen

Comment: basically set your app simplest logo as first splash screen. then set mainpage = your splash screen showing your random pic. after a delay set your real app mainpage. you would want to double the splashscreen page with a same looking popup over it that will remain on screen after you set your real mainpage and fade out.